# После редактирования шаблона email woocommerce выдаёт ошибку

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

После замены формы нового заказа выдаёт ошибку Internal Server Error. Помогите разобраться в чем проблема.
/* Код исправил, но ошибка осталась на месте, и кстати, если я хоть один do_action уберу  - сразу выдаёт internal error. */

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

echo "= " . $email_heading . " =\n\n";

echo $order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() . "\n";
if ( $order->get_billing_address_2() ) {
    echo $order->get_billing_address_1() . " " . $order->get_billing_address_2() . "\n";
} else {
    echo $order->get_billing_address_1() . "\n";
}
echo $order->get_billing_phone() . "\n";
echo "---\n";
if ( $order->get_customer_note() ) {
    echo "Комментарий\t " . wptexturize( $order->get_customer_note() ) . "\n";

echo "---\n";

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

echo "---\n";


foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
        if ($total['label'] == "Payment method") echo "Форма оплаты: " . "\t " . $total['value'] . "\n";
    }
    foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
        if ($total['label'] == "Subtotal") echo "Сумма заказа: " . "\t " . $total['value'] . "\n";
    }
    foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
        if ($total['label'] == "Shipping") echo "Доставка: " . "\t " . $total['value'] . "\n";
    }
    foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
        if ($total['label'] == "Total") echo "Итого: " . "\t " . $total['value'] . "\n";
    }

echo "---\n";

echo "Site.by";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в коде php. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум, 2 синтаксические ошибки. В строке

```
echo $order->get_billing_address_1() . " " . $order->get_billing_address_2 "\n";
```

Нет точки перед "\n".

В строке

```
 echo $order->get_billing_phone(); . "\n";
```

Лишняя точка с запятой.

На дворе 2017 год. Перестаньте пользоваться блокнотом. Поставьте себе уже нормальную среду разработки, она избавит вас от таких ошибок.

Comment: Ну не знаю, мне норм.  [Блокнот.](https://ibb.co/kpXOXm)

Comment: @Даниил очень плохо. Вы непроизводительно тратите время. Мне известны случаи, когда на работу не брали лишь за то, что код написан не по стандарту WordPress. И как вы, интересно, подключите Code Sniffer к блокноту?

Comment: Зачем?  Открываешь виндовс-блокнот пишешь, пишешь, пишешь, сохраняешь код, без проверки, даже не смотришь на результат, заливаешь на продакшен  за день до дедлайна, если ошибки есть исправляешь. Готово  

Comment: Поправил код, взгляните пожалуйста.